# Page CSS will not load - simple html and js file

Tags: css, node.js

I'm creating a simple page to start to learn HTML, CSS and java script.  I have my HTML file with the following link to my CSS file but for some reason none of CSS loads.

I running this on localhost via node.

html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link href='./css/styles.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
</head>
```

my server.js file:

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8080;

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

    if (err) throw err;

    http.createServer(function(request, response) {
        response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(html);
        response.end();
    }).listen(PORT);
});
```

I also get the error

> "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html: "http://localhost:8080/css/styles.css"."

Do I need to add another content-type for "text/css" into my server.js file?

Document tree:

[image]

Comment: you are missing an important tag. nodejs

Comment: thanks for adding the tag, i did miss that one :)

Answer (score 2):

You can add your scripts externally to your `html` page like this. It could be located inside of the `head` tags like your CSS definition.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Script_folder/server.js"></script>
```

And be carefull about reaching files in the tree. `../` means one level up and `~/` points to `root` node. So, I wonder that your routing has a certain point with a single `.` in your CSS address.

`<link href='../css/styles.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>`
with two dots. `../`

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately it did not load my css still.

Comment: I do have the following sources in my index.html file at the end of the body as i want to load all the page contents first.

<script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js'></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>

Comment: could you please post an image of the document tree. so we can see file and folder hierarchy.

Comment: added document tree

Comment: both are at the same level. `<script src="server.js" />` and `<link href='/css/styles.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>` should be enough for `index.html`.

Answer (score 0):

In href attribute you used only one dot instead of two. Your href should be like

```
  <link href='../css/styles.css' type='text/css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

Comment: based on my tree i think  one dot "." makes sense as i dont want to go up a directory then to the css folder.  i have my root folder "mySite", two folders in it, css and js and in my root is my index.html file.